# Nagios plugin to monitor health of FreeSWITCH?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, freeswitch

Is there a Nagios plugin to monitor the health of a FreeSWITCH server? It could either be on the server side or installed on the client.

The Nagios Exchange doesn't show any results for [a search of 'freeswitch'](http://search.nagios.com/search?q=freeswitch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a plugin (in Perl) that checks various health parameters on a FreeSWITCH server. It takes advantage of the *fs_cli* FreeSWITCH command-line tool. It may be extended to check practically anything that fs_cli can check.

It currently monitors a handful of things:

- sofia-status-internal - looks for the 'internal' Name and expects to find a state of RUNNING.
- sofia-status-external - looks for the 'external' Name and expects to find a state of RUNNING. Same format as the 'internal' test above.
- show-calls-count - reports total # of current calls.
- sofia-status-profile-internal-failed-calls-in - reports the FAILED-CALLS-IN parameter in the 'sofia status profile internal' query.
- sofia-status-profile-internal-failed-calls-out - reports the FAILED-CALLS-OUT parameter in the 'sofia status profile internal' query.

You may get it and more info from GitHub:
https://github.com/kjhosein/nagios-freeswitch-plugin

It requires the Nagios::Plugin Perl module (written by Ton Voon).

Answer (score 2):

Someone wrote their own health monitoring plugin and put it on [github](https://github.com/kjhosein/nagios-freeswitch-plugin) since Nagios does not offer one.

Comment: Heh, yup, that was me! I wanted to add it to SF, but can't answer my own question (yet). Low rep folks like me have to wait 8 hours. ;-)